# Is turnover of staff actually considered a problem?

Tags: hiring

It is well known that the best way to get a raise in software (and increasingly any other field) is to switch jobs. It is well known that the market is hot. It is well known that tech tenures keep falling.

So why is nothing done about it? Why does the best way to get a raise remain switching?

All I can conclude from the lack of corporate action on turnover is that we are pretty interchangeable and domain knowledge and codebase knowledge aren't considered to be worth anything, a lie to get people to do something other than just code.

Corporate complains about knowledge loss, delays getting people started on the codebase, the cost of paying recruiters, etc, but their actions price all of that at $0. The corporate world prices losses of people at $0.

Answer (score 6):

Some companies factor training costs into their budget and work to keep staff.

Other companies do little, or no, training and just headhunt the skills they need.

Some companies are between these somewhere so it's just how the world works.

You move for more money, or less overtime hours or better conditions or you choose not to move. All down to your choice.

Comment: +1 got pointing out the variety of reasons people leave.  I haven't left a job over money in well over a decade - but I have left for more growth opportunities, poor management/culture, life changes, better work/life balance

Answer (score 3):

I think it's more that you're not able to see where the cost of that knowledge comes in - employee retention.

You throw up the threat of leaving for another job and you'll see your management perk up and start offering to make all of your dreams come true if you stay, at least, for long enough to transition things for the next guy.

Developers in general, they do see as interchangeable... A good developer is great, but most managers will expect, very few people will stick around more than 3 years or so.

So, the best they can hope for is that if you leave, you'll have enough documented, or will get enough written out before you leave, that the next person ramps up okay enough.

Also, the manager isn't personally invested in it. It's an inconvenience to them, as replacing you adds some annoyance to their days when you've left, but it's not like they're physically paying the difference. It's your manager's job to push back on you asking for a raise, and at many org's, to proactively mind-screw you into thinking you don't deserve one.

Similar to how you manipulate code, managers are meant to manipulate.... us.

The reason the best way to get a raise, is to leave, is that unless you're leaving, there's no threat to the business. **There are tons of people who will sit, unhappy, at a dead-end job, for 5-10 years, with no additional money.**

They may as well see if that's you. And if you leave..... they will try and find someone else happy to *start out* at the lower rate.

It may also not be feasible to give someone the raise.... For example, if the position doesn't require or benefit from 20 years of experience, then it wouldn't make much sense to keep advancing and raising someone's pay annually for each of 20 years... They may have the thought that, hey, if we can get someone in with 2-3 years exp, they will more or less still perform the same for our menial coding job...

There's many factors that play into it. But the question of whether corporate knowledge transfer is valuable... It is, but it's something that's only addressed when there's a real threat to an employee leaving. Because the *cost* associated with losing this is only apparent to the business when an employee that *has* this knowledge is about to leave, or already has.

You see, many organizations will try to cookie-cutter their positions into as much as possible, replaceable 'cog in a machine' style jobs that can be easily replaced... because it will reduce this cost, and training times etc, for them. So they may just assume that they have this done on so many jobs already that whatever knowledge you have is probably easily replaceable.... but then when the manager realizes you've learned things that they don't have written out as well as they should have, suddenly you're worth more to keep around to prevent an operational fault in your absense.

Additionally, these facts only hold true when the market is *hot* for employees. If the organization is able to reduce the complexity of the job, or the market you're in becomes more saturated with employees, or the next pandemic strikes and many people are suddenly competing for the same small pool of jobs, you'll see management at companies working candidates against each other saying... Hey I've got a guy with 20 years of experience that can do $30/hr. Can you do $25?
Then they'll go back to the guy @ 20 years experience and say.... I really love your resume but we had someone with 18 years experience say they'd do $25 an hour. The market right now is really tough... but if you can match it, the job is yours.... And essentially they'll just see who they can get with the most experience for the least money.

We're in the back end of a boom in IT pay rates due to a significant shortage of employees vs jobs. When it goes the other way.... things will plummet.

Comment: _"We're in the back end of a boom in IT pay rates due to a significant shortage of employees vs jobs. When it goes the other way.... things will plummet."_ IMO automatation and digitalisation will even increase in the next two decades, so I guess it's safe to say that there will be an increasing demand over the next decades.. So plenty of time for us before AI will take over most of the dev work.. ;)

Comment: @iLuvLogix any market can become saturated. How many people do you suppose lost jobs in other careers as part of the pandemic and decided to pivot to IT.... There will come a day where there are too many resources, even if it's just in specific local markets D:

Answer (score 2):

> Is turnover of staff actually considered a problem?

For the most part, yes, it is considered a problem. When people leave, they leave with all of their experience, knowledge, and skills and a gap is created in whatever work they were doing. The company looses know-how, sometimes projects are closed because key people depart. If that employee goes to the competition then that's even worse. Then the company needs to spend time recruiting someone else, train them, integrate them in a team whose productivity decreases because they need to spend time to help the new member get up to speed, etc.

But things aren't so simple. There are a lot of other factors that weigh in. It also depends on who leaves (maybe you are a junior whose departure doesn't impact things badly enough for people to try to keep you instead of replacing you), maybe they can't offer you a raise to make you stay because they just don't have the budget. Maybe they were lucky to hire someone who was interested in the challenges of the job more than the salary, but after a while they get bored, now salary starts to become an issue, and the company just can't step up. It also depends on who leaves. Maybe some lazy ass#ole leaves, in which case things will actually be better without them and the company does nothing to keep them, etc.

You have to realize that a business deals with risk on a daily basis. Turnover is just one of those risks. They can try to avoid the risk (for ex, create a good company environment, invest in people, keep them engaged on interesting projects, offer proper pay, etc, so that they don't want to leave), or they can accept a risk ("there isn't much we can do if people decide to leave so that's that", fingers crossed they don't leave), or they can deal with the risk once it manifest itself (this last point is what usually happens and what you describe in your question - you can't forbid people to leave, so when that happens you deal with it then, usually by giving them more money or other opportunities).

It's really hard to know what people will do in the future so many companies just hope for the best and if somebody resigns they cross that bridge when they get to it. To give (perhaps a creepy) analogy, you can consider turnover for a project like people dying. Death is part of the human condition and can happen anytime. Do you live your life everyday thinking about death and how to prevent it? Or the death of those around you? Not likely. There are situations that are obviously life threatening and you avoid those consciously. Some other things can't always be avoided and you deal with them when they happen, like sicknesses or accidents. Companies work the same way. They don't do their business constantly thinking that they people will leave or that they need to do something to make sure they don't.

Finally, I need to mention that sadly there are also companies that have found a way to survive by taking advantage of their employees and they don't really care when their people leave because they can replace them with others that can be taken advantage of (I know a few of these). If you live paycheck to paycheck, or you have debts, or they think you can't find a job some place else easily, then you might be trapped in a job, so many companies will take advantage of that. Like I said above, things aren't simple.

Comment: +1.  There’s always some turnover (risk). In the end the company ends up needing to decide between, for example, “salary budget of $10M with 6% turnover per year or salary budget of $12M with 4% turnover a year.”  So is the $2M in extra salaries to stem 2% turnover “worth it?’  That’s the calculus leaders have to figure out. Will the downsides of the turnover impact revenue by at least $2M?

Comment: @mxyzplk I think your numbers are a bit off. 6% turnover means people stay almost 17 years on average. 15% turnover may be considered Ok, and some manage to exceed 50%, which is just horrible. But with 50% turnover, you will need more people because they don't know the job, so you can save some money until people stop leaving, but once they're gone replacing them will cost you more.

Comment: It’s an example, man.

Comment: then again, many companies make it almost a policy to let people go after a year or two rather than give them a raise and then hire new, younger people to replace them. Of course that's mostly companies where HR runs the show who don't have a clue that people aren't perfectly interchangable machines.

Answer (score 1):

**Most problems go unacted upon and unsolved as they get pushed away by something else.**

Many of us here would have done sprint retrospectives and dug up all sorts of issues. How many did you ever solve? In my anecdotal experience, few, and even fewer permanently (in large part because the issue was outside the project). I now just phase out during them, as I know the organizational bandwidth doesn't exist to fix many things. Scrum called and wanted more features and faster.

I used to be an innovation analyst at a bank and part of the team's mandate was improving the employee experience and their productivity. Tons of people reported genuine and often simple to solve issues. How many were addressed? Next to none, to the point that one employee told me we may as well give up asking when I went out to ask again. The bandwidth just didn't exist to even triage the stack. Time was allocated to collect, but we had other projects, so nothing got done.

In my own life, there are piles of small things to be done. I need to write a bio for my personal website. I have a blog post that has been half-finished for a month. I have a reference to write for someone else. I was supposed to garden with my grandfather. That was pushed aside by various things and now is again pushed aside recovering from surgery. My recovering from surgery pushed aside a bunch of work, which as it was urgently assigned pushed aside some test stuff.

Talent management seems to be like that. A priority when someone leaves but pushed aside by something else by the next day. Not a problem until you are a person short. I've heard plenty of managers complain about not retaining talent. That is usually the extent of their action.

So no, it is not really a problem as far as they are concerned as it does not maintain their attention for long.

Answer (score 1):

I will attempt a psychological explanation in this answer.

> Why does the best way to get a raise remain switching?

Imagine you are an employer.  An employee comes to you and says, "I am quite confident I could get about 30% more at a comparable position elsewhere in this hot market".  You look at some relevant job ads and you agree that it's a perfectly accurate statement.

Would you raise that employee's salary by 30%?

Rationally, you should.  In the long run, it will cost more to hire someone new, if this person leaves for a different job.

But people aren't rational.  A 30% raise *feels huge*.  What have they done to *deserve* this?  Unless they're a really exceptional performer, most managers will simply balk at this idea.  You can't give someone a *huge raise* like that, just for doing their job adequately!

> All I can conclude from the lack of corporate action on turnover is that we are pretty interchangeable and domain knowledge and codebase knowledge aren't considered to be worth anything, a lie to get people to do something other than just code.

Not a lie, but a lack of accurate perspective.  People aren't very good at weighing these two alternatives against each other.

In fact, people are generally poorer at reasoning when it is outside a social context: see the [Wason selection task](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wason_selection_task) for an example.  So, again, it *feels wrong* to give such a huge raise, and that overrides whether it is the rational decision or not.

> Corporate complains about knowledge loss, delays getting people started on the codebase, the cost of paying recruiters, etc, but their actions price all of that at $0. The corporate world prices losses of people at $0.

Hiring someone new is expensive, but often the cost of the hiring itself is externalised -- offloaded to HR rather than part of the hiring department's budget -- so from the hiring department's perspective it's zero-cost.  (I read this in an answer somewhere on Workplace.SE and if I ever locate it again, I'll link to it here.)  That probably contributes to it as well.  (You might say, people may be bad at reasoning, but institutions are even worse at it!)

Answer (score 1):

Each industry has a different tolerance for turnover.

McDonald's famously had a 200% turnover rate at one time, about double the average for the fast food industry, which caused them ti take action to bring them down to the industry average.

From fast food to retail to IT, there are built in tolerances for knowledge loss and turnover.

When those tolerances are exceeded it is a problem.  Most skilled trades, any turnover can be a problem.

Now, when a company wants to cut back by attrition, it will be higher.  This can be driven by a desire to divest in a market.

TLDR: Some companies or industries, it isn't a concern depending on the direction of the company or nature of the industry.

Answer (score 0):

I think its easy to over think this. Your analysis from first principles is correct and high turnover is bad and good companies will try to retain good staff.
I mean this is management 101. Since you are not doing work, the way your add value as a manager is to hire, motivated and retain good people.
But so many places have bad management that yell at their staff let alone offer pay rises proactively.
A good workplace needs some mechanism for giving pay raises internally. Ideally it should be communicated upfront and systematic and not in reaction to people wanting to leave.
I've worked at places that sound like your experience and also places that tie pay to progression/ performance. I.e. you just turn up do a good job and manager actively gives you a pay rise. No tantrums / negotiations